# Xcode / React Native - "Transform Error - unknown plugin 'module-resolver' "

Tags: xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, babeljs

I am running a build on Xcode for my React Native project and for some reason, when running the build in debug mode, this error appears: 
'TransformError: [my directory] : Unknown plugin "module-resolver" ' inside my babelrc file.

I tried to npm install the module-resolver to see if that would get rid of the error however the simulator still has as red screen with that same TransformError.

Any help/guidance on this would be really helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install the 'babel-plugin-module-resolver'.

You should run:
`npm install babel-plugin-module-resolver --save-dev`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver